# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a simple form to do a database query.  The database is accessed via password which I've included in the code.  I'm not sure why I keep hitting the error on the string escape and the undefined variable *$query = htmlspecialchars($query);*

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Search2.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['query'])) 
 $query = $_POST['query']; 

if (!empty($query)) 

    $query = $_POST['query']; 
    // gets value sent over search form


        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Staff
            WHERE (`LastName` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`FirstName` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());


        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<p><h3>".$results['LastName']."</h3>".$results['FirstName']."</p>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }


    ?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You indented your code, but didn't put a { after the if statement. The { is required to have more than one line of code inside the if statement.

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you've invoked a `mysqli` object with your credentials, however, later you try to execute with the `mysql_` procedural method. You don't have a connection there. You need to stick with the `mysqli` object. Furthermore, you should use prepared statements to handle your user input on SQL queries.

Remove these, we don't need to do sanitization for prepared statements:

```
//BYE!
$query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection
```

Now let's use the mysqli object and OOP prepared methods. However, first we need to construct our like statements as our query's variables aren't executed, you can't concatenate `%?%` directly into the `prepared()` statement.

```
$query = '%'.$query.'%';

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Staff
        WHERE LastName LIKE ? OR FirstName LIKE ?");
```

Now we can bind the parameters to our `$stmt` object.

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $query, $query);
```

Let's execute it now and get our data back.

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Then we can loop:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<p><h3>".$result['LastName']."</h3>".$result['FirstName']."</p>";
}
```

**Edit**

You also don't need to escape your column names with a backtick because:

- They don't have `-` in the name
- They aren't reserved special words in MySQL.

Comment: I think I see where you're going with this.  I did try running it but I got an  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING here - $stmt->bind_param('ss', $query, $query);

Comment: @Tony Please check again, in my hasted response, I'd omitted the `);` on the `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(` line. My apologies.

Comment: I looked right at it, saw it and thought you knew something about structure that I didn't so I ignored it.  I made the change but still keep getting the syntax error on that other line syntax error, unexpected T_STRING here - $stmt->bind_param('ss', $query, $query);  where is the 'ss' coming from?

Comment: @Tony Okay....There was another syntax error in the prepared statement as it started with `'` and then `"`. I've fixed that. The `'ss'` is a `type-identifier`. the `'s'` stands for `string` in this case, and it's letting the bind param function know that the 2 variables we're going to pass in should be treated as strings.

Comment: I saw that in the select statement but thought it was closed.  I didn't know that about the identifier.  I've only been working with MySQL and PHP a few months and it's been taking me to school haha.  Now it doesn't like the = on the execute line.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your PHP version is below 7.0 as stated here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Warning
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
mysqli_real_escape_string()
PDO::quote()